# Xubuntu 18.04 で、`Alt+PrintScreen`にコマンドを割り当てる方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

## 環境

- XUbuntu 18.04

## やりたいこと

`Alt+PrintScreen`キーにコマンドを割り当てたいです。

ショートカットは、「キーボード⇨アプリケーションショートカットキー」アプリで割り当てます。

## 質問

`Alt+PrintScreen`を割り当てようとしましたが、「キー受付」モードで`Alt+PrintScreen`を入力すると、`Alt+L`と表示されました。
また`Alt+PrintScreen`を入力しても、`test`コマンドが実行されまんでした。

どのようにすれば、`Alt+PrintScreen`キーを割り当てることができますか？

---

追記:
`Alt+PrintScreen`はマジックSysRqキーに割り当てられていました。Alt+Print+oを押したら、システムが終了しました。
Alt+PrintをSysRqに割り当てないようにするには、どうすればよいでしょうか？ ちなみに、私のキーボードにはSysRqキーが存在しません（ThinkPad T460s）。

Comment: Alt+Print は [マジックSysRqキー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B8%E3%83%83%E3%82%AFSysRq%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC) かも知れないですね。（だからといって、キーイベントを取れないわけでは無いと思いますが）

Comment: おっしゃる通りマジックSysRqキーに割り当てられていました。`Alt+Print+o`を押したら、システムが終了しました。

Comment: `Alt+Print`を`SysRq`に割り当てないようにするには、どうすればよいでしょうか？
ちなみに、私のキーボードにはSysRqキーが存在しません（ThinkPad T460s）。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SysReqの機能自体を無効にする方法を紹介しておきます。

**現在の設定状況を確認**
(以下はCentOS7での確認結果。`1`以上の値だと何らかのコマンドが有効になっている。)

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
16
```

**SysReqの機能をすべて無効にする**

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq"
```

上記コマンドではOS再起動で設定がリセットされるので、常に無効とするなら`/etc/sysctl.conf`に設定を記述してOSを再起動する。

**OS起動時に無効となるよう設定**

```
$ sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.sysrq = 0
```

参考:
[Magic SysRq Key の使い方と機能と実装 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Kernel_OGSun/items/6e540792a576e577e06f)
[初期設定でマジックSysRqキーを有効にするには - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/a055enablesysrq.html)